# Multiple if statements inside ViewBuilder fails building

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am getting the error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" when trying the following code.

I found out that breaking up the syntaxes into smaller bits would help but its still not working. I also tried specifying the data types still the error persists.

This code works if there is only one "if statement"

```
ScrollView{
            ForEach(discoverManager.discoverResponse, id: \.id) { discoverSection in
              LazyVStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(discoverSection.title ?? "").fontWeight(.bold)
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                  
                  if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == "users", let users: [ProfileDatas] = discoverSection.users {
                    HStack{
                      ForEach(users, id: \.self){ user in
                        let image: String = user.userProfile?.avatar ?? "default.jpg"
                        let name: String = user.userProfile?.firstName ?? user.username ?? ""
                        let role: String = user.defaultRole ?? ""
                        let uploadedTime: String = user.createdAt ?? ""
                        DiscoverLargeSlide(imageUrl: image.createImageURL(), title: name, uploader: role, uploadedTime: uploadedTime)
                          .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  
                  if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == "genre", let genres: [SubgenreItem] = discoverSection.genre {
                    HStack{
                      ForEach(genres, id: \.self){ genre in
                        let image: String = genre.image ?? "default.jpg"
                        let title: String = genre.subGenre ?? ""
                        DiscoverSqaureSlide(imageUrl: image.createImageURL(), title: title)
                          .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  
                  
                }
              }
              .padding(.leading, 12.0)
            }
            
            Text("Hello")
}
```

Comment: switch tends to be more efficient but this is too much "work" for a `body` move the logic into a separate class or struct

Comment: Try giving reproducible example.

Comment: Note, you have a `ScrollView` containing a `ForEach`, containing another `ScrollView`
 containing multiple `ForEach` loops. Really, re-structure your code to be more modular.

Comment: literally the error explain itself " try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" divid this view into subviews and it will work

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you very much for your response. How would you suggest it to be more modular? I need a vertical scrollview with multiple horizontal scrollviews which will be displayed according to an API response.

Comment: @AhmedMohiy Thank you very much for your response. What would be the best way to divide these into subviews? I am pretty weak with SwiftUI.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you very much for your response. Is it possible for you to explain what would be considered as "too much work" in a view builder a bit more?

Comment: There isn’t a set definition for it but multiple conditionals, unwrapping multiple optional, running functions, comparisons, using self in ForEach.

Answer (score -1):

when it comes to divide your code into smaller pieces you have three options

1. wrap the code in a variable inside your struct
2. wrap the code in a function inside your struct if you want to pass some parameters to that chunk of code
3. wrap the code in completely new struct and that will be a separate view you can actually use it in multiple parts of your code without repeating the same code over and over

It is also important to remove the logic code from your swiftUI and added to another class or struct and here comes the role of the  viewModel

so i started by removing the unnecessary code and added a function instead to  do the if conditions in it

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        ForEach(discoverManager.discoverResponse, id: \.id) { discoverSection in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(discoverSection.title ?? "").fontWeight(.bold)
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    collectionHorizontalList(discoverSection: discoverSection)
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 12.0)
        }
        
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

let's take a look at this function collectionHorizontalList(discoverSection: discoverSection)

```
func collectionHorizontalList(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> some View {
    var views:[HorizontalListType] = []
    
    if isUserListType(discoverSection: discoverSection) == .user {
        views.append(.user)
        
    }
    
    if isGenereListType(discoverSection: discoverSection) == .genere {
        views.append(.genere)
    }
    
    if views.isEmpty {
        return EmptyView()
    }
    
    
    return VStack {
        ForEach(views, id: \.self) { type in
            switch(type) {
            case .user:
                DiscoverLargeSlideView(viewModel: DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel(users: getUserDictionary(from: discoverSection)))
            case .genere:
                DiscoverSqaureSlideView(viewModel: DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel(genres: getGenereDictionary(from: discoverSection)))
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

i created var views:[HorizontalListType] = [] to hold all the views to be shown from if conditions
then i simplified the if condition to be easy to understand it's important to do that so your code be very easy on the eyes  and to be readable.

those are the condition functions

```
func isUserListType(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> HorizontalListType {
    if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == CollectionNameType.users.rawValue, let users = getUserDictionary(from: discoverSection) {
        return .user
    }
    
    return .none
    
}

func isGenereListType(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> HorizontalListType {
    if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == CollectionNameType.generes.rawValue, let genres  = getGenereDictionary(from: discoverSection){
        return .genere
    }
    
    return .none
}
```

they holding just the checking pretty straight forward and i created enums just to make the code more cleaner and remove any string literal checks

this part return and empty view just when both if conditions failed because the function expect a view to be returned

```
if views.isEmpty {
        return EmptyView()
    }
```

last part of this function is the returned VStack as you can see it loops over the views array and check the type and return the corresponding views and instead of writing the login of names and images inside the swiftui views i made a view model for each of the view and logic will be inside those view models
lets take a look on the first view which is called DiscoverLargeSlideView

```
 struct DiscoverLargeSlideView: View {
 let viewModel: DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack{
            ForEach(viewModel.users, id: \.self){ user in
                DiscoverLargeSlide(imageUrl: viewModel.getImage(from: user),
                                   title: viewModel.getName(from: user),
                                   uploader: viewModel.getRole(from: user),
                                   uploadedTime: viewModel.getUploadedTime(from: user))
                    .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it's viewModel

```
class DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel {
    var users: [AnyObject]?
    
    init(users: [AnyObject]? = nil) {
        self.users = users
    }
    
    func getUsers() -> [AnyObject] {
        return users ?? []
    }
    
    func getImage(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.userProfile?.avatar ?? "default.jpg"
    }
    
    func getName(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.userProfile?.firstName ?? user.username ?? ""
    }
    
    func getRole(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.defaultRole ?? ""
    }
    
    func getUploadedTime(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.createdAt ?? ""
    }
}
```

it's straight forward as well you have the view and all the logic inside the view model and you get all the parameters for this view DiscoverLargeSlide from the view model and it's better to create a view model for DiscoverLargeSlide and give it the whole user object and inside it you get what you want from the user object you get the idea i guess ??

and here is the second view which i called DiscoverSqaureSlideView

```
struct DiscoverSqaureSlideView: View {
    
    let viewModel: DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack{
            ForEach(viewModel.getGeneres(), id: \.self){ genre in
                DiscoverSqaureSlide(imageUrl: viewModel.getImage(from: genre),
                                    title: viewModel.getTitle(from: genre))
                    .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and of course it's view model

```
class DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel {
    var genres: [AnyObject]?
    
    init(genres: [AnyObject]? = nil) {
        self.genres = genres
    }
    
    func getGeneres() -> [AnyObject] {
        return genres ?? []
    }
    
    func getImage(from genere: AnyObject) -> String {
        return genre.image ?? "default.jpg"
    }
    
    func getTitle(from genere: AnyObject) -> String {
        return genre.subGenre ?? ""
    }
    
    
}
```

**And here is the whole code**

```
import SwiftUI

enum HorizontalListType {
    case none
    case user
    case genere
}

enum CollectionNameType: String {
    case users = "users"
    case generes = "genre"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(discoverManager.discoverResponse, id: \.id) { discoverSection in
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text(discoverSection.title ?? "").fontWeight(.bold)
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        collectionHorizontalList(discoverSection: discoverSection)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 12.0)
            }
            
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
    
    func getUserDictionary(from discoverSection: AnyObject) -> [ProfileDatas]? {
        return discoverSection.users as? [ProfileDatas]
    }
    
    func getGenereDictionary(from discoverSection: AnyObject) -> [SubgenreItem]? {
        return discoverSection.genre as? [SubgenreItem]
    }
    
    func isUserListType(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> HorizontalListType {
        if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == CollectionNameType.users.rawValue, let users = getUserDictionary(from: discoverSection) {
            return .user
        }
        
        return .none
        
    }
    
    func isGenereListType(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> HorizontalListType {
        if let collectionName: String = discoverSection.collectionName, collectionName == CollectionNameType.generes.rawValue, let genres  = getGenereDictionary(from: discoverSection){
            return .genere
        }
        
        return .none
    }
    
    
    func collectionHorizontalList(discoverSection: AnyObject) -> some View {
        var views:[HorizontalListType] = []
        
        if isUserListType(discoverSection: discoverSection) == .user {
            views.append(.user)
            
        }
        
        if isGenereListType(discoverSection: discoverSection) == .genere {
            views.append(.genere)
        }
        
        if views.isEmpty {
            return EmptyView()
        }
        
        
        return VStack {
            ForEach(views, id: \.self) { type in
                switch(type) {
                case .user:
                    DiscoverLargeSlideView(viewModel: DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel(users: getUserDictionary(from: discoverSection)))
                case .genere:
                    DiscoverSqaureSlideView(viewModel: DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel(genres: getGenereDictionary(from: discoverSection)))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


// DiscoverLargeSlideView

class DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel {
    var users: [AnyObject]?
    
    init(users: [AnyObject]? = nil) {
        self.users = users
    }
    
    func getUsers() -> [AnyObject] {
        return users ?? []
    }
    
    func getImage(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.userProfile?.avatar ?? "default.jpg"
    }
    
    func getName(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.userProfile?.firstName ?? user.username ?? ""
    }
    
    func getRole(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.defaultRole ?? ""
    }
    
    func getUploadedTime(from user: AnyObject) -> String {
        return user.createdAt ?? ""
    }
}

struct DiscoverLargeSlideView: View {
    let viewModel: DiscoverLargeSlideViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack{
            ForEach(viewModel.users, id: \.self){ user in
                DiscoverLargeSlide(imageUrl: viewModel.getImage(from: user),
                                   title: viewModel.getName(from: user),
                                   uploader: viewModel.getRole(from: user),
                                   uploadedTime: viewModel.getUploadedTime(from: user))
                    .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
            }
        }
    }
}

// DiscoverSqaureSlideView

class DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel {
    var genres: [AnyObject]?
    
    init(genres: [AnyObject]? = nil) {
        self.genres = genres
    }
    
    func getGeneres() -> [AnyObject] {
        return genres ?? []
    }
    
    func getImage(from genre: AnyObject) -> String {
        return genre.image ?? "default.jpg"
    }
    
    func getTitle(from genre: AnyObject) -> String {
        return genre.subGenre ?? ""
    }
    
    
}

struct DiscoverSqaureSlideView: View {
    
    let viewModel: DiscoverSqaureSlideViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack{
            ForEach(viewModel.getGeneres(), id: \.self){ genre in
                DiscoverSqaureSlide(imageUrl: viewModel.getImage(from: genre),
                                    title: viewModel.getTitle(from: genre))
                    .frame(width: metrics.size.width * 0.8, height: metrics.size.height * 0.2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's important not to keep all that code in one file try to divided into multiple files as well. this code has errors because i don't know the type of your objects so i added AnyObject as a type for all the objects. i just chose to divide the code as what you provided in tour question it might be a better way to name the functions and maybe create more custom views. I wrote the code just to give you an idea what can be done but based on your code and based on your app you can customize it more.

**as a rule of thumb if you have to scroll to see the whole body variable in any swiftUI view that body needs to be divided in smaller pieces**

Good luck and enjoy coding.